# Can access one JIRA Board via rest API, but not an other

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

In our company I inherited a .net project that uses REST API calls to access JIRA boards. The ID of the board is given as a parameter, and the URL is concatenated, e.g. to
https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/agile/latest/board/1

Everything was fine, and after said team (and board) went from Scrum to Kanban, the new Board ID was 2, so all I had to do was to change the parameter value from 1 to 2.

Now we introduced a new team and project to JIRA, they now have a board with ID 3. And while I can access 
https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/agile/latest/board/3
in a browser as easily as for board 1 and 2, the project is getting a 404 error when trying to access the board.

I just don't get the difference. I thought that enabling API calls was a general setting in JIRA, not project-specific. And even if it was project-specific, I should not be able to access the URL via a browser...from what I know, but I'm far from being an expert, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Florian

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using a technical user to make these REST API calls. Have you checked if that user has access to the new project? If the user does not have access to the project or board, Jira returns a 404 error.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it, thanks a lot.